# How Variance of error term is equal to the conditional variance of y given x in linear regression

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning, linear-regression

How the variance of the error term is equal to the conditional variance of y given x in linear regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming your model assumption is something like
$$y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon$$
where $\epsilon$ is noise and is independent of $x$.

If you are conditioning on $x$, then the only random quantity is $\epsilon$, so $y$ is just $\epsilon$ plus some non-random quantities. Shifting a random variable does not change its variance.
$$\text{Var}(y \mid x) = \text{Var}(\alpha + \beta x + \epsilon \mid x)
= \text{Var}(\epsilon \mid x) = \text{Var}(\epsilon).$$
The last step is due to independence of $\epsilon$ and $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was very helpful.